# Default values in metadata

Tags: 2011, schema

We have a metadata schema `TestSchema` with a text field having default value as 001 and a field having radio buttons yes and No where No is default value.

One of the scenario where, once I select the above metadata schema and say save then select any other metadata schema and save.

Finally,

> again select `TestSchema` metadata schema then the default values are
>   not populated

(Text box is cleared and none of the radio buttons is selected). Is this OOB behaviour? Is there a hotfix to fix the same or are we missing something?

Please note, this is happening on all the browsers and it is not browser specific issue.

Comment: Can you share some more details about in what browser you are experiencing this behavior, and if you see the same in different browsers? Also it can't hurt to add some spacing in your question, right now it is one paragraph of text, which I personally do not find easy to read (but that might just be me).

Comment: Even if OOB consider checking with Support providing the browser details, any sources you have, and where this happens (pages, folders, SGs?). I'd expect defaults to show between changes, but what happens when you change metadata schema selections *without* saving? Do the metadata schemas share any of the same field names?

Comment: Hello, were you able to take this with support? Is there any hotfix available?

Answer (score 2):

I have observed this behaviour on my 2013 SP1 system, so I suppose it's been there for a while. I tested with an ordinary component schema, and indeed, for a radio button, the defaultTextValue doesn't show up when you create a component. I'd recommend that you report this issue to support.

In the meantime, you can work around this by changing the List Type to Drop Down List.

Answer (score 0):

`This is OOB behavior.`
 The work around for this problem is, whenever you have selected any metadata schema and change it to some other metadata schema before that change it to none and save it.

For e.g. metadata schema TestSchema with a text field having default value as 001 and a field having radio buttons yes and No where No is default value. Select the above metadata schema and say save then select any other metadata schema and save.

Before reverting back to again TestSchema, first change the metadata schema to None and save it and then select TestSchema then default values will be populated.